# SQL Query for Data Consolidation

Tags: sql, oracle

this is my first question in here.. I have 4 different tables as follows i want consolidate data as shown in the picture using SQL query preferably joins.. I am wondering if anyone could help me with this!

Data Tables:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mourya,  -  welcome to SO. Before you get too far, please read this note (from the Help center) about how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask    And this too: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Then, please edit your post to choose the relevant tags (Is it MySQL? Is it Oracle?)   Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it (using the WITH clause to provide sample data):

```
with table_a (col1, col2)
as
(select 'X', 10 from dual
  union all
 select 'Y', 30 from dual
  union all
 select 'Z', 50 from dual
)
, table_b (col1, col2)
as
(select 'M', 10 from dual
  union all
 select 'X', 20 from dual
  union all
 select 'Y', 30 from dual
)
, table_c (col1, col2)
as
(select 'N', 10 from dual
  union all
 select 'Y', 50 from dual
  union all
 select 'Z', 70 from dual
)
, table_d (col1, col2)
as
(select 'M', 10 from dual
  union all
 select 'N', 50 from dual
  union all
 select 'Z', 70 from dual
), 
 distinct_col1
as
(
SELECT col1
  FROM table_a
 UNION 
SELECT col1
  FROM table_b
UNION 
SELECT col1
  FROM table_c
UNION 
SELECT col1
  FROM table_d
)
SELECT d1.col1
     , t_a.col2 as a_col2
     , t_b.col2 as b_col2
     , t_c.col2 as c_col2
     , t_d.col2 as d_col2
  FROM distinct_col1 d1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table_a t_a
          ON d1.col1 = t_a.col1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table_b t_b
          ON d1.col1 = t_b.col1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table_c t_c
          ON d1.col1 = t_c.col1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table_d t_d
          ON d1.col1 = t_d.col1
ORDER BY d1.col1
```

With physical tables table_a, table_b, table_c, and table_d this is just:

```
with distinct_col1
as
(
SELECT col1
  FROM table_a
 UNION 
SELECT col1
  FROM table_b
UNION 
SELECT col1
  FROM table_c
UNION 
SELECT col1
  FROM table_d
)
SELECT d1.col1
     , t_a.col2 as a_col2
     , t_b.col2 as b_col2
     , t_c.col2 as c_col2
     , t_d.col2 as d_col2
  FROM distinct_col1 d1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table_a t_a
          ON d1.col1 = t_a.col1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table_b t_b
          ON d1.col1 = t_b.col1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table_c t_c
          ON d1.col1 = t_c.col1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table_d t_d
          ON d1.col1 = t_d.col1
ORDER BY d1.col1
```